# Is it relevent to set “requests” values if i’m not using HPA?

Tags: kubernetes, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I was wondering if it was really relevant to set “requests” (CPU/MEM) values if I’m not using HPA ?

If those values are not used to scale up or down some pods, what is the point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine and it will work if you don't provide the **requests** (CPU/MEM) to workloads.

But consider the scenario, suppose you have 1-2 Nodes with a capacity of **1** **GB** and you have not mentioned the **requests**.

Already running application utilizing half of the node around **0.5 GB**. Your new app needs now **1 GB** to start so K8s will schedule the PODs onto that node as not aware of the minimum requirement to start the application.

After that whatever happens, we call it a **Crash**.

If you have extra resources in the cluster, setting affinity and confidence in the application code you can go without putting the requests (**not best practice**).

Comment: Thank you very much for this very clear answer.
And do I really have to follow the recommendations to set the values?
For example, for Velero, the recommended requests seem to be 500Mi but, in reality, most of the time the pod consumes only 2Mi. 
Can I put 2Mi or 5Mi for example without affecting the application? Or can there be unexpected behavior or bugs?

Comment: If there recommended value it would be better to use, with velero i have noticed it goes up to 200 or so, sometime when taking a backup of existing namespace resources etc. would recommend using the suggested one and also keep extra space to be safer side.

Comment: So a too low Request can affect the behavior of a pod? Even if I set a very high Limit?

Comment: Yes definitely it will affect the app performance